# Which one is correct: "not in A or B" or "not in A and B"?

Tags: word-choice

Which sentence would sound more natural?

> Can not find it in my house OR your house.

> Can not find it in my house AND your house.

Comment: OR when you're using a negative 'can not'.  AND example: I can not find it. I looked in my house AND your house.

Comment: I would say "I cannot it find in my house nor yours."

Answer (score 2):

I'd say this:

> I can't find it in your house **or** my house.

I think most native Anglophones would.